# Pass product variables by user selection

Tags: variables, magento, controller

I want to make a ticket sales site theme. As you might guess, most of ticket sales site using a flash based chair selection tool. Those systems using premade scenes which is audiences can select their chairs. I can make premade scenes with jQuery or flash but I don't know how can we handle this selection by Magento.

So, what I want to know that is it possible to pass a user specific variable in Magento? I mean, this variable should be available in checkout and backend as well. Could you please give me an advice to accomplish such an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this option can be selected from a fixed list of options, then what you want can be achieved using Configurable Products, or Custom Options.

If what you're looking for is a completely bespoke user-defined value, then this is pretty programming intensive, so if you're not a developer it's not an easy task.

Forgive the shameless self-link, but I've recently posted on this topic here:

http://mikebywaters.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/adding-custom-data-to-a-cart-item-in-magento/

In short, the post says that you can add an array of custom data to the quote when the item is added to the quote. For this, you’ll have to hijack the add-to-cart controller completely. To start with, take all the functionality from the existing controller. Look at the Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addProduct() function and you’ll see that it takes two parameters like so:

```
$quote->addProduct($product, $request);
```

where $request is of type Varien_Object formatted like this:

```
$request = new Varien_Object(array(
    'qty'=>$qty,
    'options'=>$options,
    'custom_options'=>$custom_options 
));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mike, thank you for article. First approach isn't suitable for me is because of the amount of the chairs (it depends on the scene, there are 4 saloon). Also, could you please little bit explain option B?

Comment: Sure. It's a concept that you'll be able to use elsewhere. Basically you'll need to build a custom module and model. If you haven't done this prior, I'd say it's important to stop now and work through these tutorials in order: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento - They're very useful if you haven't done them already. Your Model will need to be configured with a database table that stores the custom data and related Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item and Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item entity_id's. Add functions to your models that ...

Comment: return the associated sales/quote_item and sales/order_item objects, and override those model classes to add functions that return a collection of your custom data models.